# Other networks built off of Ethereum?

Tags: network, networkid

It looks like if I wanted to I could have the same private and public key for: Ethereum, Ethereum Classic, Tomochain, Vechain, Wanchain, and Aion networks because they were all built on a copy of Ethereum.

What other networks exist like this? Is there a comprehensive list somewhere?

(It got me thinking about a fun scavenger hunt: give a key but don't tell what network it is. Let the race begin!)

Answer (score 1):

I'll start

```
|------------|--------------------------------|------------|-------|---------|------------| 
| Chain ID   | Name                           | Short Name | Chain | Network | Network ID | 
| 1          | Ethereum Mainnet               | eth        | ETH   | mainnet | 1          | 
| 100        | xDAI Chain                     | xdai       | XDAI  | mainnet | 100        | 
| 101        | EtherInc                       | eti        | ETI   | mainnet | 1          | 
| 108        | ThunderCore Mainnet            | TT         | TT    | mainnet | 108        | 
| 11         | Metadium Mainnet               | meta       | META  | mainnet | 11         | 
| 1122334455 | IPOS Network                   | ipos       | IPOS  | mainnet | 1122334455 | 
| 12         | Metadium Testnet               | kal        | META  | testnet | 12         | 
| 1313114    | Ether-1                        | etho       | ETHO  | mainnet | 1313114    | 
| 13371337   | PepChain Churchill             | tpep       | PEP   | testnet | 13371337   | 
| 162        | Lightstreams Testnet           | tpht       | PHT   | sirius  | 162        | 
| 1620       | Atheios                        | ath        | ATH   | mainnet | 11235813   | 
| 163        | Lightstreams Mainnet           | pht        | PHT   | mainnet | 163        | 
| 18         | ThunderCore Testnet            | TST        | TST   | testnet | 18         | 
| 18289463   | IOLite                         | ilt        | ILT   | mainnet | 18289463   | 
| 1856       | Teslafunds                     | tsf        | TSF   | mainnet | 1          | 
| 1987       | EtherGem                       | egem       | EGEM  | mainnet | 1987       | 
| 2          | Expanse Network                | exp        | EXP   | mainnet | 1          | 
| 200625     | Akaroma                        | aka        | AKA   | mainnet | 200625     | 
| 24484      | Webchain                       | web        | WEB   | mainnet | 37129      | 
| 246529     | ARTIS sigma1                   | ats        | ARTIS | sigma1  | 246529     | 
| 246785     | ARTIS tau1                     | ats        | ARTIS | tau1    | 246785     | 
| 269        | High Performance Blockchain    | hpb        | HPB   | mainnet | 100        | 
| 28945486   | Auxilium Network Mainnet       | aux        | AUX   | mainnet | 28945486   | 
| 3          | Ethereum Testnet Ropsten       | rop        | ETH   | ropsten | 3          | 
| 30         | RSK Mainnet                    | rsk        | RSK   | mainnet | 30         | 
| 31         | RSK Testnet                    | trsk       | RSK   | testnet | 31         | 
| 31102      | Ethersocial Network            | esn        | ESN   | mainnet | 1          | 
| 3125659152 | Pirl                           | pirl       | PIRL  | mainnet | 3125659152 | 
| 385        | Lisinski                       | lisinski   | CRO   | mainnet | 385        | 
| 4          | Ethereum Testnet Rinkeby       | rin        | ETH   | rinkeby | 4          | 
| 42         | Ethereum Testnet Kovan         | kov        | ETH   | kovan   | 42         | 
| 5          | Ethereum Testnet Görli         | gor        | ETH   | goerli  | 5          | 
| 6          | Ethereum Classic Testnet Kotti | kot        | ETC   | kotti   | 6          | 
| 60         | GoChain                        | go         | GO    | mainnet | 60         | 
| 61         | Ethereum Classic Mainnet       | etc        | ETC   | mainnet | 1          | 
| 61717561   | Aquachain                      | aqua       | AQUA  | mainnet | 61717561   | 
| 62         | Ethereum Classic Testnet       | tetc       | ETC   | testnet | 2          | 
| 64         | Ellaism                        | ella       | ELLA  | mainnet | 64         | 
| 76         | Mix                            | mix        | MIX   | mainnet | 76         | 
| 77         | POA Network Sokol              | poa        | POA   | sokol   | 77         | 
| 7762959    | Musicoin                       | music      | MUSIC | mainnet | 7762959    | 
| 8          | Ubiq Network Mainnet           | ubq        | UBQ   | mainnet | 1          | 
| 820        | Callisto Mainnet               | clo        | CLO   | mainnet | 1          | 
| 821        | Callisto Testnet               | tclo       | CLO   | testnet | 2          | 
| 88         | TomoChain                      | tomo       | TOMO  | mainnet | 88         | 
| 9          | Ubiq Network Testnet           | tubq       | UBQ   | mainnet | 2          | 
| 977        | Nepal Blockchain Network       | yeti       | YETI  | mainnet | 977        | 
| 99         | POA Network Core               | skl        | POA   | core    | 99         |
```

### Reference :

- [Chainid.network](https://chainid.network)

Comment: Thank you for this list. However because it doesn't include Vechain, Wanchain, and Aion, it doesn't seem like a very complete list to answer the scope of my question.

Comment: You are for chains built off Ethereum  not EVM compatible chains...

Comment: @gero Please add missing chains via PR to https://github.com/ethereum-lists/chains

Answer (score 0):

`0xsegfault` Could you please update this list (it's been a few years)? I've been trying to put together a list of chains built off of Ethereum (which your list does perfectly), particularly the names, network IDs, and chain IDs. Ideally, such a list would include historical information as well (Olympic, Frontier, etc.), but I would be more than happy with an updated version of this excellent list you put together on the subject. Sources seem to sometimes conflate network ID and chain ID, and I can't find any source that distinguishes chains built on Ethereum specifically.